# Game fails to start with Fast but no exceptions on

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm trying to optimize my game for better performance. So I'm trying to enable script call optimization to use Fast but no exceptions on rather than Slow and Safe. The problem is that when in that mode i'm getting that error:

```
PropertyToID can only be called from the main thread.
```

I googled about it and found out that it's probably caused by some shader. But I don't know how to find out which one or where. It should be some call in constructor or so.

Only things I'm changing on shaders are done in `OnPostRender()` function. I assume that's ok.

Comment: Are you using `System.Threading` or some other threading API?  That error is usually seen when trying to use a Unity class in another thread.

Comment: Only where I am using System.threading is in TextMeshPro plugin https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/17662. Could it be that that plugin is bugged? I'm using it in whole project, so realy annoying to disable it.

Comment: Check your debug to find where `PropertyToID` is being called, if it's inside a worker thread that's likely the issue.  The problem with fast optimization is that it "doesn't explicitly handle exceptions", the error you mention might have always been around but it was quietly hidden.

Comment: I dont find that anywhere in debug. Should it be in warnings or where?

Comment: Does your error not give you line location?  IDR if thread warnings give such info.  If not, do a global search for `PropertyToID` to narrow down the call site(s).  Hopefully there are only a few and you can review the code to figure out which methods are called from a worker thread.

Comment: I'm getting that error when I'm already runing in xcode, so no line. If i search true my code there is no PropertyToID, but appereantly some others calls use it...

Answer (score 0):

Make a sure that you doesn't call `Shader.PropertyToID` from any constructor or field initializers. Instead of this move this code to `Awake()` or `Start()` methods. Something like this:

```
class MyClass: MonoBehaviour
{
    int somePropertyID = Shader.PropertyToID("SomePropertyID");   //<-- ERROR: this is field initializer

    MyClass()                                                     //<-- ERROR: this is constructor 
    {
        somePropertyID = Shader.PropertyToID("SomePropertyID");
    }

    void Awake()                                                   //<-- THIS IS OK!
    {
        somePropertyID = Shader.PropertyToID("SomePropertyID");
    }

    void Start()                                                   //<-- THIS IS OK!
    {
        somePropertyID = Shader.PropertyToID("SomePropertyID");
    }
}
```